# How to create Quickstart Installation package for prestashop 1.7?

Tags: installation, prestashop

I want to **create Prestashop theme quickstart package**, But I did not found any way.

For more details..
I want to deliver to my client the template, that I have designed on my localhost.

And **client can install theme's quickstart package same as prestashop 1.7 installation with theme's  sample data like products, categories, banner, images all.**

Small help will be highly appricaited.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom Prestashop distribution by following those [guidelines](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/8/basics/deployment/distribution/).
This would allow to include custom modules and automatically enable them during install steps.

However I am not sure if there is a way to force also custom theme installation without tweaking the installer, so why not just packing the theme [the standard way](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/8/themes/distribution/exporting/) and include your theme modules as dependencies (with also a "import demo data tool" if needed ?). This is how almost all Prestashop third party themes are distributed.

Another option, if you'd like to provide your customers a ready to use environment with custom themes / already hooked modules, is providing him a ready-to-use ZIP package with already installed environment + SQL database dump.